# Conversion failed when converting character string to uniqueidentifier error from asp.net application but not from SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I have a query which is executing perfectly when run from SSMS. But that same query is throwing the error mentioned in the title when executed from my asp.net (ado.net) application.

Here is the query:

```
select 
    [computed column]
from 
    [externaldb].dbo.[table1] t1
where 
    t1.userid in (select t2.userid 
                  from [synextdbusers] t2 
                  where t2.guid in (select t3.guid 
                                    from [mydb].dbo.[users] t3 
                                    where t3.guid is not NULL)
                    and t2.guid is not NULL)
```

- `t1.userid` and `t2.userid` are of data type `bigint`
- `t2.guid` is `uniqueidentifier`
- `t3.guid` is `nvarchar`, `[externaldb]` is an external database and `[mydb]` is database where given query is executed
- `[synextdbusers]` is synonym to a table on external database

Any explanation is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) I assume that this error is generated during evaluation of following predicate `where t2.guid in (select t3.guid ...)`. According to data type precedence, `UNIQUEIDENTIFIER` (`t2.guid`) has higher precedence than `NVARCHAR` (`t3.guid`). Because of this reason, SQL Server will execute an implicit conversion from  of `t3.guid` values from `NVARCHAR` (lower precedence) to `UNIQUEIDENTIFIER` (higher precedence) which is the same as `CONVERT(UNIQUEIDENTIFIER, t3.guid)`. If `t3.guid`  / `NVARCHAR` column contain invalid `UNIQUEIDENTIFIER` values (ex. empty strings) then an error will be raised. Why this query performs totally different on SSMS ? One simple explanation come from execution plan: the execution plans could be different thus:

a) The execution plan associated with query sent from WebApp avoids reading bad `NVARCHAR` values from `t3.guid` column.

b) Execution plan associated with query sent from SSMS have a diff. data access path. This time, the XP forces SQL Server to read bad values (invalid `UNIQUEIDENTIFIER`s) from `t3.column`.

2) Why there are diff. execution plan for the "same" query ? Two reasons: (2.1) the `SET` sessions settings are different for WepApp connection compared with settings for SSMS. Diff. settings and/or (2) [parameter sniffing](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2013/06/the-elephant-and-the-mouse-or-parameter-sniffing-in-sql-server/). Because of one of these reasons, execution plans are different.

3) Following query return these settings:

```
SELECT s.session_id, s.program_name, s.login_name, s.nt_domain, s.nt_user_name, s.quoted_identifier, s.ansi_nulls, s.ansi_warnings, s.* -- see other SETttings 
FROM sys.dm_exec_sessions s
WHERE s.session_id IN (<WebApp spid>, <SSMS spid>)
```

4) To check if there are one or more XP for the same SP you could use following query:

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED
SELECT  pln.query_plan, ps.*
FROM    sys.dm_exec_procedure_stats ps
OUTER APPLY sys.dm_exec_query_plan(ps.plan_handle) pln
WHERE   ps.database_id = DB_ID() -- Check DB for current session
AND     ps.object_id = OBJECT_ID('dbo.ProcName')
```

or

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED
SELECT *
FROM (
SELECT 
    SUBSTRING(qt.text,qs.statement_start_offset/2 +1, 
                 (CASE WHEN qs.statement_end_offset = -1 
                       THEN LEN(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), qt.text)) * 2 
                       ELSE qs.statement_end_offset END -
                            qs.statement_start_offset
                 )/2
             ) AS query_source_code, 
     qp.query_plan AS query_xplan
FROM sys.dm_exec_query_stats AS qs 
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(qs.sql_handle) AS qt 
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_query_plan(qs.plan_handle) AS qp
) x
WHERE x.query_source_code LIKE '%select 
    [computed column]
from 
    [externaldb].dbo.[table1] t1
where 
    t1.userid in (select t2.userid 
                  from [synextdbusers] t2 
                  where t2.guid in (select t3.guid 
                                    from [mydb].dbo.[users] t3 
                                    where t3.guid is not NULL)
                    and t2.guid is not NULL)%'
```

5) Quick demo:

```
USE tempdb
GO
DROP TABLE dbo.InvoiceDetail
DROP TABLE dbo.Invoice 
GO
CREATE TABLE dbo.Invoice (ID INT PRIMARY KEY, InvoiceDate DATE)
CREATE TABLE dbo.InvoiceDetail(ID INT PRIMARY KEY, InvoiceID INT REFERENCES dbo.Invoice(ID), Qty INT, UnitPrice INT, ProductID NVARCHAR(36))
GO

CREATE INDEX OX_InvoiceDetail_InvoiceID_#_ProductID
ON dbo.InvoiceDetail (InvoiceID) 
INCLUDE (ProductID)

INSERT dbo.Invoice VALUES 
(101, '2016-01-01'), 
(102, '2016-02-02'),
(103, '2016-03-03')
GO

INSERT dbo.InvoiceDetail (ID, InvoiceID, Qty, UnitPrice, ProductID)
VALUES 
(1, 101, 11, 10, ''),
(2, 102, 22, 20, '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'), 
(3, 103, 33, 30, '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'),
(4, 103, 44, 40, '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000')
GO
--DELETE dbo.InvoiceDetail WHERE ID = 0

SELECT  i.InvoiceDate, id.ProductID
FROM    dbo.Invoice i INNER JOIN dbo.InvoiceDetail id ON i.ID = id.InvoiceID
WHERE   i.InvoiceDate >= '2016-02-02'
AND     id.ProductID = NEWID()
OPTION (FORCE ORDER)
GO

SELECT  i.InvoiceDate, id.ProductID
FROM    dbo.Invoice i INNER JOIN dbo.InvoiceDetail id ON i.ID = id.InvoiceID
WHERE   i.InvoiceDate >= '2016-02-02'
AND     id.ProductID = NEWID()
OPTION (HASH JOIN)
GO
```

Results:

```
InvoiceDate ProductID
----------- ------------------------------------

(0 row(s) affected)

InvoiceDate ProductID
----------- ------------------------------------
Msg 8169, Level 16, State 2, Line 36
Conversion failed when converting from a character string to uniqueidentifier.
```

**Note: last two queries are similar but because I used those query hints the XP will be also different** (in this case).

[image]